# Finding unique Values from a file

Tags: csv

I have a 6 mb sized csv file. I want to filter the data by column A & Column C so that I need to remove any duplicates. What is the easiest way to do it and how to do it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Easiest way possible is what i want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use cut or awk to select fields. Sort and uniq to remove duplicates. FOr example

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' A.csv|sort|uniq
```

Comment: I dont know any of these command line tools. Can u help me with the commands too pls

Comment: can you explain what the command does ? I didnt get this part "," '{print $1}'

Answer (score 10):

```
cat foo.csv | cut -f2 -d , | sort | uniq
```

It will give you unique ids from 2nd column

```
cat foo.csv | cut -f1 -d , | sort | uniq
```

It will give you unique ids from 1st column

```
-f < number > : column number

-d  < space >< delimiter > : file delimiter
```